# Handling "no operator found"

Tags: c++

I haven't learned `operators` in c++ yet so I do not understand what does compiler want from me. Here is a full code and error pops up in `AStar` class. I understand that the problem (maybe) is because I want to get size of `vector<Node>` and have to do something extra, but do not understand what.

Could anybody help me and tell what should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


struct Node {
    int i;
    int j;
    double g;
    double h;
    double f;
};


class AStar {
public:
    double getG(int i, int j) { // dist from starting node
        return pow(i, 2) + pow(j, 2);
    }
    double getH(int i, int j) { // dist from ending node
        double a = pow(goal_i - i, 2);
        double b = pow(goal_j - j, 2);
        return a + b;
    }
    double getF(double g, double h) {
        return g + h;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> g; // graph
    stack<Node> path;
    set<Node> setVisited;
    double goal_i;
    double goal_j;
    AStar(vector<vector<int>> graph, int goalI, int goalJ) {
        // set goal i, j
        goal_i = goalI;
        goal_j = goalJ;
        // set graph as class variable
        g = graph;
        // create first node
        Node firstNode;
        firstNode.i = 0;
        firstNode.j = 0;
        firstNode.g = getG(0, 0);
        firstNode.h = getH(0, 0);
        firstNode.f = getF(firstNode.g, firstNode.h);
        // set first node to path as a begining
        path.push(firstNode);
        // set first node as visited
        setVisited.insert(firstNode);
    }

    stack<Node> start() {
        // choose the current node
        Node currentNode = path.top();
        while (currentNode.i != goal_i && currentNode.j != goal_j) {
            //if no path exist
            if (path.size() == 0) {
                stack<Node> noPathStack;
                return noPathStack;
            }
            // get all its available neighbours
            Node neighbour = getBestNeighbour(currentNode);;
            // check if neighbour is chosen:
            if (neighbour.i == currentNode.i && neighbour.j == currentNode.j) { // if no unvisited neighbours left
                path.pop();
                setVisited.insert(neighbour);
            }
            else { // if neighbour has been chosen
                path.push(neighbour);
            }
            Node currentNode = path.top();
        }
        return path;
    }

private:
    vector<Node> getNeighbours(Node node) {
        vector<Node> neighbours;
        // check if this neighbour is not out of bounds of the graph
        // if not add it to neighbours vector
        int numberOfNeighbours = 0;
        if (node.i < goal_i && node.j < goal_j) {
            if (node.i != goal_j) { // if bottom of the graph is not reached
                Node checkNeighbourNode1;
                checkNeighbourNode1.i = node.i + 1;
                checkNeighbourNode1.j = node.j;
                checkNeighbourNode1.g = getG(checkNeighbourNode1.i, checkNeighbourNode1.j);
                checkNeighbourNode1.h = getH(checkNeighbourNode1.i, checkNeighbourNode1.j);
                checkNeighbourNode1.f = getF(checkNeighbourNode1.g, checkNeighbourNode1.h);
                neighbours.push_back(checkNeighbourNode1);
            }
            if (node.j != goal_j) { // if right bound of the graph is not reached
                Node checkNeighbourNode2;
                checkNeighbourNode2.i = node.i;
                checkNeighbourNode2.j = node.j + 1;
                checkNeighbourNode2.g = getG(checkNeighbourNode2.i, checkNeighbourNode2.j);
                checkNeighbourNode2.h = getH(checkNeighbourNode2.i, checkNeighbourNode2.j);
                checkNeighbourNode2.f = getF(checkNeighbourNode2.g, checkNeighbourNode2.h);
                neighbours.push_back(checkNeighbourNode2);
            }
            // if diagonal right down node == 14 add it as neighbour otherwise don't
            if (g[node.i + 1][node.j + 1] == 14) {
                Node checkNeighbourNode3;
                checkNeighbourNode3.i = node.i + 1;
                checkNeighbourNode3.j = node.j + 1;
                checkNeighbourNode3.g = getG(checkNeighbourNode3.i, checkNeighbourNode3.j);
                checkNeighbourNode3.h = getH(checkNeighbourNode3.i, checkNeighbourNode3.j);
                checkNeighbourNode3.f = getF(checkNeighbourNode3.g, checkNeighbourNode3.h);
                neighbours.push_back(checkNeighbourNode3);
            }
        }   
        return neighbours;
    }

    bool neighbourVisited(Node node) {
        return (setVisited.count(node)) ? true : false;
    }

    Node getBestNeighbour(Node node) {
        vector<Node> neighbours = getNeighbours(node);
    
        // for all neighbours
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++) {
            // if neighbour is not visited
            if (neighbours[i].i == goal_i && neighbours[i].j == goal_j) {
                return neighbours[i];
            }
            if (!neighbourVisited(neighbours[i])) {
                return neighbours[i];
            }
        }
        // if all neighbours visited
        return node; // returning input node means there is no unvisited neighbours left
    }
};


class MillerMyers {

public:

    string seq_1; // rows
    string seq_2; // cols
    vector<vector<int>> graph;
    int row_size;
    int col_size;
    MillerMyers(string Sseq_1, string Sseq_2) {
        row_size = Sseq_1.length();
        col_size = Sseq_2.length();
        seq_1 = Sseq_1;
        seq_2 = Sseq_2;
        setWeights();
    };

    vector<vector<int>> getGraph() {
        return graph;
    }

    void printGraph() {
        cout << "  ";
        for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
            cout << seq_2[i] << " "; // cols
        }
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) { // rows
            cout << seq_1[i] << " ";
            for (int j = 0; j < col_size; j++) {
                cout  << graph[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

private:

    int getWeight(int i, int j) {
        if (seq_1[i] == seq_2[j]) {
            return 14;
        }
        else {
            return 20;
        }
    }
    void setWeights() {
        // for each node we set weight
        // 2    if it is simple node that chains UP, LEFT nodes
        // 1.41 if it is node that chain UP, LEFT and UPPER-LEFT node.
        for (int i = 0; i < row_size; i++) {
            graph.push_back(vector<int>());
            for (int j = 0; j < col_size; j++) {
                int weight = getWeight(i, j);
                graph[i].push_back(weight);
            }
        }
    }

};


vector<pair<int, int>> getstack(stack <Node> s) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> path;
    while (!s.empty()) {
        path.push_back(make_pair(s.top().i, s.top().j));
        s.pop();
    }
    return path;
}


int main() {
    string seq_1 = "AGTCCTT";
    string seq_2 = "AGTTTCT";
    MillerMyers mm(seq_1, seq_2);
    vector<vector<int>> graph = mm.getGraph();
    AStar astar(graph, seq_1.length(), seq_2.length());
    stack<Node> path = astar.start();

    // show the stack
    vector<pair<int, int>> vecPath = getstack(path);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vecPath.size(); i++) {
        cout << vecPath[i].first << " " << vecPath[i].second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MillerMayers, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MillerMayers.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xstddef(141): error C2678: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\system_error(319): note: could be 'bool std::operator <(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\system_error(312): note: or       'bool std::operator <(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xstddef(141): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const _Ty, const _Ty)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xstddef(140): note: while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Kty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=Node,
1>            _Ty=Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility(1110): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'bool std::less<_Kty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=Node,
1>            _Ty=Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility(264): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Kty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=Node
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xutility(264): note: see reference to variable template 'const bool is_empty_v<std::less<Node> >' being compiled
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xtree(1032): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_comp_alloc<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tset_traits<Node,std::less<Node>,std::allocator<Node>,false>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\set(55): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=Node,
1>            _Pr=std::less<Node>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<Node>
1>        ]
1>c:\users\horseman.mini\source\repos\millermayers\millermayers\millermayers.cpp(41): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::set<Node,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=Node,
1>            _Ty=Node
1>        ]
1>Done building project "MillerMayers.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

P.S. I added here `Miller class` for checking `AStar class`, beacuse `AStar` takes graph from `Miller`

**EDIT 1**

I added

```
// overloading operator
Node operator<(const Node& n) {
    Node n;
    return n;
}
```

under the `AStar constructor` and above `start` function, but now error is

```
1>...ers\millermayers.cpp(65): error C2082: redefinition of formal parameter 'n'
```

**SOLUTION FOR THOSE WHO GOOGLE SUCH A PROBLEM**

I needed to specify how set should  sort `Node` objects, so I added go global space this function:

```
bool operator< (const Node& node1, const Node& node2) {
    return node1.f < node2.f;
}
```

Instead of `node1.f < node2.f` here could be any method how you can compare 2 objects.

Comment: Operator < must take the form `bool operator<(const Node& right_side)` if a member or `bool operator<(const Node& left_side, const Node& right_side)` and should return true if `this` or `left_side` is less than `right_side`. How you determine less than with a `Node` is up to you. I have no idea what any of its member variables represent and can't offer any good input.

Comment: Cause of the error in edit 1: there are two `n` identifiers defined in the same scope. This is not allowed. Which is the real `n`, `const Node& n` or `Node n;`? The compiler doesn't know, so it rejects the code.

Comment: @user4581301 `Node.i`, `Node.j` represents node on the matrix, `g,h,f` is just some parameters. I use set only for fast defining have I met this Node before in this algorithm or not, not for comparing, so It doesn't matter how comparison will be done

Comment: If you can't compare `Node`s you can't use a `set`. `set` is an associative container and its association is based on the [strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) of objects placed in the `set`.

Comment: @user4581301 but I am already using set which contains of Nodes, isn't it? Or what do you mean

Comment: I mean `set<Node> setVisited;` cannot work without a rule for correctly ordering `Nodes`. An [`unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) may work better for you, since you don't care about ordering, but `unordered_set` requires a rule (a function) for creating a hash value for `Node`s that tries for uniqueness or at least a wide spread of `Node`s to minimize collisions.

Comment: @user4581301 can I add `id` to `Node` and function will sort Nodes by their unique id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with std::set. You have a set of Nodes, but the template parameter of a set must have a  < operator declared. The compiler error sais, in fact, that you should "see reference to std::set". Either you should declare a < operator for Nodes, or use your custom sorting function for the std::set.

Comment: How do I write my custom function for sorting set by `Node.i`, `Node.j`? I just need somehow to store them in set and thats it so for now it doesn't really matter

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm explains operator overloading.

Comment: More wisdom on operator overloading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: Regarding your other questions: you can define an id and order the nodes according to the ID. The ids should be different for each node. Also, mark the question as answered if you consider ot answered.